# Failed to load map.php - CORS policy

Tags: php, api, cors

i created book sharing php web application here i am using google maps api i was storing coordinates in database and after i fetching those information using xml.

Few hours ago some error is coming when i am trying to fetching the data from xml file.

searchbook.php:1 Failed to load http://localhost/libro/map.php?q=god%20delusion: Redirect from 'http://localhost/libro/map.php?q=god%20delusion' to 'http://localhost/libro/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://libro-book-share.000webhostapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enabled cross-origin ressource sharing in yur php file.
To do so, put this line at the beginning of your php file

```
 <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Here is an article explaining in detail cors 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control

hope it helps you